# Iterating Through Dictionary To Get Value Using Regex

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I am learning Python and I have this variable in Python and I want to find the value for both profit rate and interest rate.

```py
banks = [{'bank_code': 'BANKA',
         'profit_rate': 2.7},
         {'bank_code': 'BANKB',
          'interest_rate': 2.6}]
```

If I iterate the dictionary this way:

```py
for i in range(len(banks)):
    rate = banks[i]['profit_rate']
    print(rate)
```

It will only print:

```
2.7
```

If I iterate the dictionary this way:

```py
for i in range(len(banks)):
    rate = banks[i]['profit_rate' or 'interest_rate]
    print(rate)
```

The result will show an error.

So how can I iterate and get the value for both profit and interest rate? Someone said to me to use regex but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: The direct way is to use a if statement to check whether it exists.

Comment: No, regex isn't useful for extracting information from dicts. It's used for extracting information from strings.

Comment: Generally, if you are using `range(len(..))` you are on an unpythonic road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help

```
banks = [{'bank_code': 'BANKA',
  'profit_rate': 2.7},
{'bank_code': 'BANKB',
  'interest_rate': 2.6}]

for bank in banks:
    x = list(bank.keys())[1]
    print(bank[x])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, [`truth value testing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

```
 for k in banks:
    print(k.get('profit_rate') or k.get('interest_rate', 0))
```

Comment: What if `profit_rate` exists but is 0 or otherwise falsey?

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to iterate through the list.

```
banks = [{'bank_code': 'BANKA',
  'profit_rate': 2.7},
{'bank_code': 'BANKB',
  'interest_rate': 2.6}]

print(*[' '.join([el.get('bank_code'),'prof='+str(el.get('profit_rate')),'rate='+str(el.get('interest_rate'))]) for el in banks],sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
BANKA prof=2.7 rate=None
BANKB prof=None rate=2.6
```

[Program finished]